# How to list a a Facebook friend list in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, facebook, api

Can anyone give me a simple example of how to list a friend list from Facebook in VB.NET?

Also, what SDK should I install for VB.NET?

Answer (score 4):

If you're entirely against writing code in C#, you can just compile the [Facebook C# SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395) to a DLL and import it into your VB project.  At that point there'd be no difference between the two.

Comment: OK I have it as a DLL now what to do?

Comment: @kmitnick: What is it you want to do?  "List the friend list from Facebook" isn't particularly specific.  You can use the SDK (limited as it is at the moment, I'll admit that) to interface with the Facebook Graph API.  There's a good bit of reading on the subject: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: thnx then :) All I needed is a guide I am new to the Facebook API

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/)
 works fine with VB.NET.

However it doesn't support out of the box Graph API and Graph API authentication.

You can get friends list with code like this (I am not sure formatting for `Writeln()` method is correct):

```
' autheticate first
For Each item As Facebook.Schema.user In api.Friends.GetUserObjects
    Console.Writeln("uid: {0}", item.uid)
    Console.Writeln("picture: {0}", item.pic_small)
    Console.Writeln("first name: {0}", item.first_name)
    Console.Writeln("last name: {0}", item.last_name)
Next
```

Comment: In short -- it depends on kind of app (desktop/webapp) and API you use. I am sure there are already a few good answers for your question somewhere else on Stackoverflow.