# Is the an simple examples of Facebook API with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

please bear in mind, I am doing this as a hobby

I currently have created a page in VB.Net and brought that page into a FB app and now showing that in one of my pages on there.

Currently it shows everything to all users, but I would like to only show the intro to non-fans and everything else to fans. I did find an app but the items I am showing are dynamic from my own website.

So that's number 1, 2 is, when they are fans, collect data from them, such as name and email address and profile picture.

I found the C# SDK, but way above my head right now.

I tend to work really well with full sample examples, so if you have come across any, it would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: we work better with full questions as opposed to requests to do the work for you. You should read up on the [Facebook Api Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) and revise your question to be more direct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark cooney you can browse the github for code examples and api's https://github.com/facebook  i do not know any my self that support vb.net.

Some samples here on overlfow [How to list a a Facebook friend list in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538934/vb-net-and-facebook-api)